# check url extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have about 10 domains, al going to the same website (a .com), http and https.
Now on my website I want to check via htaccess if the entered domain is .com or not, and if not redirect to the .com. How can I do this?

Example: vistor types in www.mywebsite.org
  -> redirect to www.mywebsite.com

Example 2: vistor types in https://www.mywebsite.eu
  -> redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(org|eu)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.com/$1  [R,L]
```

You can add the other TLD's in the `(org|eu)` bit, separated by a |